# Use and utility of std::shuffle?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, shuffle, stl-algorithm

If you look to the specifications of random shuffle in C++11, there are 3 functions. My question is what is the typical use and advantage of :

```
template< class RandomIt, class URNG >
void shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URNG&& g );
```

compared to:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void random_shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

I mean, it seems that whatever URNG is (a uniform distribution), the result will be the same (from a statistical point of view). The only point I see, is that `std::shuffle` is thead-safe, whereas this overload of`std::random_shuffle` is not. Could you confirm that ?

EDIT: I thought that URNG should be a uniform distribution but that does not seem to compile. So can someone provide a little example of use of `std::shuffle`?

Comment: Well, the first one lets you chose the random number generator. The second one doesn't.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that the result is the same. How exactly are you calling `std::shuffle`?

Comment: @Xeo, when I say "the same" I mean "statistically the same".

Comment: The URNG is a random *engine*, like `std::mt19937`.

Comment: @URNG So I missed the "uniform" point. Is there any non-uniform random engine in `<random>` (wathever this means) ?

Comment: @Vincent, you can wrap it into the distribution object e.g. `normal_distribution` instance (see more here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/)

Comment: You can find a little example of std::shuffle at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `std::shuffle` takes a *random number generator* (or *engine* in standard speak), not a *random number distribution*. Different random number generators have different characteristics even if they have a theoretically uniform distribution.

- **Random** or **pseudo-random** - True random number generators use some sort of an external entropy source. Pseudo-random generators (PRNGs) are strictly deterministic.
- **Performance** - some generators are faster than others.
- **Memory usage** - some PRNGs need more memory to store their state than others.
- **Period length** - all PRNGs have a finite period after which they start repeating the same sequence from the beginning. Some have much longer periods than others.
- **Randomness quality** - there are [numerous tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test) for measuring whether there are subtle (or not-so-subtle!) patterns in a pseurorandom stream. See, for example, the [Diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests).
- Whether the stream is **[cryptographically secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)** or not. AFAIK, none of the standard PRNGs are.

For an overview of the different generators offered by the standard, please refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random.